# Is there any synonymous idiom or phrase for "a win-win situation"

Tags: idioms, phrase-choice

This is the passage:

> but this situation is a **win-win** game for the system cause if the prisoners can post a bail they had benefited the system with their money and if they can’t they again had benefited the system by populating the prisons.

I'm just looking for an idiom or phrase that matches the best here, I had search on the internet but the results weren't what be appropriate for this concept.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possible phrase which means "win-win" and that is:

> It is a **no lose** situation

which means whatever the outcome, it is considered a **win**.
But given your example, it is not necessarily a no lose situation, as no lose implies it's good for everyone whatever the outcome.

Comment: The meanings are not identical; win--win refers to two parties, both of who are satisfied with a solution, while no-lose refers to a choice where any choice taken results in a positive outcome.

Comment: @Mark Ripley so, I had misused the "win-win" word in my text? I think what Peter says is what I must have used right of bat, right? (According to given context I mean)

Comment: @user48 If you are trying to show that 'the system' wins no matter which decision a prisoner makes, that is a no-lose (from the system's view). It is also a no-lose (from the prisoner's view). if any decision made benefits the prisoner.  If a particular decision benefits both the prisoners and the system as a result, this is a win-win; where both parties (prisoner and system) benefit. A decision can be both a 'no-lose' and 'win-win' only if  >>any<<  decision results in a benefit for both the system and the prisoner.